# How can i access to sql server from windows batch

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I want to connect to Sql server and running some sql queries. How can i do that?
Thank you for helps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the SQLCMD utility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702.aspx

Works not only on SQL Server 2008 Express, but also on the full versions, too.

Answer (score 0):

You really need more detail in your question.

Based on my most common experiences, though, if you're just running some queries and putting the results somewhere, you'd want to create a SSIS (SQL 2k5 or 2k8) or DTS (SQL 2k5 and before) package and either have Windows schedule call the package or call it through your .bat file.

Comment: You mean SQL 2k and before for DTS.